# Почему при обучении нейросети нельзя просто вычислить ошибку и подставить такие веса, при которых ошибка будет равна 0?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Приведу пример:

```
weight = 0.5
goal_pred = 0.8
input = 0.5

for iteration in range(20):
    pred = input * weight
    error = (pred - goal_pred) ** 2
    **direction_and_amount = (pred - goal_pred) * input**
    weight -= direction_and_amount

    print(f"{iteration + 1}) Prediction: {pred}    Error^2: {error}")
```

Почему в данном примере(в месте, выделенным жирным) нельзя вместо умножения на input сделать операцию деления? Тогда бы нужный вес нашёлся уже на второй итерации.

Я новичок, поэтому, возможно, вопрос покажется глупым. Прошу строго не судить.

Comment: Ну наверное потому что это очень упрощённая модель. В нейросети этих весов обычно очень много, а ошибка - только одна, на выходе нейросети. И нет линейной зависимости на самом деле весов от ошибки, там нелинейно всё и хитро. Почитайте про градиентный спуск и т.д., например. 
Если есть линейное решение, то всё хорошо и просто, но в таком случае обычно и нейросеть не нужна.

Comment: Представьте себе множество точек на плоскости. Процесс обучения пытается найти такую __прямую__ которая минимизирует ошибку. Т.е. такую прямую которая показывает тренд (аппроксимация). Для того чтобы ошибка была нулевой - все точки на плоскости должны лежать на одной прямой. Иначе ошибка не может быть нулевой

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что нейросеть по сути имплементирует некую **очень сложную** функцию. Реальная (хоть сколько-нибудь полезная) сеть состоит из большого числа нейронов. Входной сигнал, по мере движения через пространство синапсов, многократно интерферирует сам с собой, т.е. изменение всего одного веса в середине скрытого слоя приводит к изменению сигнала на всех нейронах во всех последующих слоях до самого выхода. Правильные веса синапсов являются неизвестными, а задачу подбора весов можно выразить, как систему нелинейных уравнений с огромным множеством неизвестных. Для общего случая эта задача просто не имеет аналитического решения - приходится подбирать веса итеративно, крошечными шагами, в ходе градиентного спуска.